# Luhn algorithm using Stream API

Tags: java, integer, stream

Example

```
String creditCardNumber1 = "4561261212345467";
        int sum = IntStream.range(0, creditCardNumber1.length()).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).map(i -> Character.getNumericValue(creditCardNumber1.charAt(i))).sum() + IntStream.range(0, creditCardNumber1.length()).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).map(i -> Character.getNumericValue(creditCardNumber1.charAt(i)))
                .map(value -> {
                    int newValue;
                    if ((newValue = value * 2) > 9) {
                        newValue = newValue - 9;
                    }
                    return newValue;
                }).sum();
        System.out.println(sum % 10 == 0);
```

I want to do it by using only one Stream because my code Is unreadable and not effective, is It possible?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot help but ask myself if they don't teach you methods anymore today.

Use *methods* whith *meaningful names*, use *variables* with *meaningful names*, when you do streams use *line breaks* with *one operation per line*. Refrain from supposedly "clever tricks" like doing an actual calculation in an if.

Rewrite of your code (whithout testing or understanding, just formally):

```
String creditCardNumber1 = "4561261212345467";
int sumOfOddNumbers = IntStream.range(0, creditCardNumber1.length())
    .filter(this::isOddNumber)
    .map(creditCardNumber1::charAt)
    .mapToInt(Character::getNumericValue)
    .sum()

int sumOfWhateverThisIs = IntStream.range(0, creditCardNumber1.length())
    .filter(this::isEvenNumber)
    .map(creditCardNumber1::charAt)
    .mapToInt(Character::getNumericValue)
    .map(this::giveThisMethodAGoodNameWhichExplainsWhatItDoes)
    .sum();

int sum = sumOfOddNumbers + sumOfWhateverThisIs;

System.out.println(sum % 10 == 0);
    
private boolean isOddNumber(int number) {
    return i % 2 != 0;
}
    
private boolean isEvenNumber(int number) {
    return i % 2 == 0;
}

private int giveThisMethodAGoodNameWhichExplainsWhatItDoes(int number) {
    int newValue = number * 2;
    if (newValue > 9) {
        newValue = newValue - 9;
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: You could also use `Predicate.not( this::isEvenNumber )` if you want to reduce the number of own methods

Answer (score 0):

To only have one stream, push down the decision of separating odd and even values:

```java
int sum = IntStream.range(0, creditCardNumber1.length())
    .map(i -> {
        int value = Character.getNumericValue(creditCardNumber1.charAt(i));
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            value = value * 2;
        }
        return value;
    })
    .map(value -> value > 9 ? value - 9 : value)
    .sum();
System.out.println(sum % 10 == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with one stream like this:

````
public static int calculateLuhnChecksum(String creditCardNumber) {
  int luhnSum = IntStream.range(0, creditCardNumber.length())
    .mapToInt(i -> {
      char c = creditCardNumber.charAt(i);
      int value = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    
      if(isEven(i)) { // i % 2 != 0 - remember, index starts with 0, so you have "even" numbers at odd indices
        value *= 2;
      }

      return sumOfDigits(value);
    })
    .sum();

  return (luhnSum * 9) % 10;
}

private static int sumOfDigits(int value) {
  if(value > 9) {
    return value - 9;
  }

  return value;
}
```
````